# How can I print the contents of an array alongside it's position?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm trying to get each item in the array printed out, alongside it's position. eg.

```
bear[0]
```

here's the code:

```
animals = ["bear", "ruby", "peacock", "kangaroo", "whale", "platypus"]

for i in animals
    puts i
end
```

Comment: Although it might seem strange, `for` is hardly ever used in Ruby. The [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html) library is just way too useful in comparison. Every time I've seen it used, it was actually the wrong way to do something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ruby it is idiomatic to use the methods provided by the [`Enumerable` module](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html) which are mixed into the [`Array` class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html) instead of using traditional `for`-loops:

```
animals.each_with_index { |x,i| puts "#{x}[#{i}]" } # => animals
# bear[0]
# ruby[1]
# peacock[2]
# kangaroo[3]
# whale[4]
# platypus[5]
```

The PickAxe Book mentions this in its section about [Blocks and Iterators](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_containers.html#S2).

Answer (score 1):

You can write it as

```
animals.each_index { |ind| puts "animal-#{animals[ind]} at #{ind}" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several ways to go about it:

```
1. animals.each_with_index do |key,index| 
    puts "#{key}[#{index}]"
   end

2. animals.each_index do |index| 
    puts "#{animals[index]}[#{index}]"
   end

3. i = 0
   animals.each do |animal|
     puts "#{animal}[#{i}]"
     i += 1
   end

4. for i in 0..animals.length
    puts "#{animals[i]}[#{i}]"
   end
```

Comment: You could mention #3, but what's the point of reiterating answers already given by others?

Comment: You may be right. But giving a good name for #1 and printing the output in desired format for #2 would make more sense. :)

Comment: Yes, `key` is more descriptive than `x`, but considering the receiver is a hash, it shouldn't slow the reader down, and yes, @Arup's output is not quite what was asked, but imo the appropriate response is to merely leave a comment informing him of such.